# CacheFS for writing while the remote server is down

Tags: caching, filesystems

I know there're several [CacheFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CacheFS) to speed up the read while working with a remote file server. But I'm looking for one that can cache all the writes to the local disk while the remote server is down and auto sync with the remote server once the server is back online.

Is there any existing tool for that? It would be better if it works with NFS server and Ubuntu client.